# How do I create a JOptionPane.showOptionDialog box in Java (Swing) with custom JButtons?

Tags: java, swing, jbutton, jdialog, joptionpane

After reading through all the Dialog tutorials for a while, there seems to be no apparent way to do this.  The closest thing seems to be `JOptionPane.showOptionDialog`, but I am limited by the `optionType` parameter here.

EDIT: I figured out the problem, but have a new one.  It seems that the `options` parameter being specified in `showOptionDialog` needs to be fairly simple objects (strings or just 'objects', not `JButton` or the like).  I was trying to put an array of custom-factory-created JButtons here, because they have a special rollover icon that I want to be using.  What happens, though, is that clicking on any of these buttons does not cause the dialog to close (and thus, execution continues blocking on the dialog).  So I have updated my question in the headline.

Put more succinctly -- the question is, how do I override `JOptionPane.showOptionDialog(args)` to get the button customization I'm looking for?  Or do I even need to do that?

Please and thanks! -B.

Comment: If three options are insufficient, you may want to reconsider this approach. The three-button dialog is already massively confusing to most users, and any additional buttons are unlikely to alleviate that. If the user needs to make a choice that complex, then maybe allow to them to make it in multiple steps. Alternatively, you may want to just remove one or two of the options (especially if they're lower impact, or unlikely to be a common choice.)

Answer (score 7):

This Java doc should help you create your own dialogs, or customize existing ones: [How To Make Dialogs](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/components/dialog.html) and if thats not what you want then maybe  creating a `JDialog`, adding the necessary components and buttons and making it visible would do the trick :)

Comment: @Billy M. JRadiobuttons in the ButtonGroup or better could be JComboBox

Comment: @David Kroukamp, Thanks David, although I don't need to drastically change the way the dialog works.  I simply need to add a rollover icon to each button in the box.

Comment: @BillyM. : **" I don't need to drastically change the way the dialog works. "** , `JDialog` is meant to work like this, for added functionality that you can not attain with `JOptionPane`, you use `JDialog`, it's easy that way :-)

Comment: showOptionDialog is very limited. You will need to use the JDialog class